# How to get data of json file for chart.js diagram

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I want to read a .json file and use its data for the data attribute of a chart.js diagram.

My code is as follows:

```
const test = []

fetch("./load.json")
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // console.log(data)
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // console.log(data[i])
        test.push(data[i])
    }
});

console.log(test)

// setup block
const data = {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sales',
            data: test,
            borderColor: 'rgba(234,124,234,0.4)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,14,24,0.4)'
        }]
};
// config block
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'second'
                }
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    min: 1628373600,
                    max: 1628460000
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
// render / init block
const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

My .json file:

```
[{"x": "2021-08-08T13:12:23", "y":3},
    {"x": "2021-08-08T13:12:45", "y":5},
    {"x": "2021-08-08T13:12:46", "y":6},
    {"x": "2021-08-08T13:13:11", "y":3},
    {"x": "2021-08-08T13:14:23", "y":9},
    {"x": "2021-08-08T13:16:45", "y":1}]
```

I have tried to parse the data from the .json file and in console it shows up but I think the data attribute of chart.js is not able to read the data in the test variable.

Does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the chart is being made before the data is ready since loading the json is an async proces, you can either instantiate the chart in your second `.then` when the data is available or create the chart as you do and then in the second `.then` update the data in the chart and call the `update` method

Comment: Updating the data in the second .then() function worked for me